# Django ForeignKey Works for Filter but not List Display

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-admin

I am trying to list a ForeignKey value in Admin list_display.  I am trying the solution below which seems to be the solution everyone uses, but I just get an error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'first_name'`

Have I listed this correctly?  Thank you.

**Plaque Model**

```
class Plaque(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='plaques', default=1)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Group Name')
    veteran = models.ForeignKey(Veteran, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

**Model Admin**

```
class PlaqueAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'get_veteran', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'branch', 'group', 'draft']

    def get_veteran(self, obj):
        return obj.veteran.first_name

    get_veteran.short_description = 'Veteran'
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't with the id at all, it's with `get_veteran()`. One of your plaques has no veteran, and thus raises an error. You should return a blank value (or something else) if there is no veteran:

```
def get_veteran(self, obj):
    if obj.veteran is not None:        
        return obj.veteran.first_name
    else:
        return ''
```

Note also that you can traverse relationships in `list_display` - I'm not 100% certain however that it won't raise the same error if veteran is null though - looking through docs and my own code to find something similar to yours.

```
class PlaqueAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'veteran__first_name', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'branch', 'group', 'draft']
```